# Lock tree algorithm deadlock detection

Tags: algorithm, tree, locking, deadlock, detection

I've been working on some examples of the Lock tree deadlock detection algorithm and been unable to figure out how a deadlock occurs in this particular situation:

```
Thread 1:           Thread 2:

lock(A)             lock(E)
lock(C)             lock(D)
unlock(C)           unlock(D)
lock(B)             unlock(A)
lock(D)             lock(A)
lock(E)             lock(C)
unlock(E)           unlock(C)
unlock(D)           unlock(A)
unlock(B)
unlock(A)
```

From my understanding the Lock tree should look something like this:

```
  T1:          T2:
              /  \
  A          E    A
 / \         |    |
C   B        D    C
    |
    D
    | 
    E
```

Could it be that the deadlock occurs at nodes T1: D - E  and  T2: E - D, because the threads take those locks in opposite order?

How could I suggest insertion of one lock and one unlock statement to remove the deadlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thread 1 does: lock(a), lock(c),unlock(c),lock(b),lock(d)

so now a,b and d are locked

thread 2 does: lock(e), lock(d)

so now e is locked as well and thread 2 is waiting for d to unlock

now thread one wakes up and does: lock(e)

now they are stuck -

1 is waiting for 2 to unlock e.

2 is waiting for 1 to unlock d

one of the methods to avoid this is to lock everything you need at once, and not as separate operations.

Comment: Oh, I see it now! Thank you. I have one additional question, though. If I added T2: **lock(b)**, lock(e), lock(d), would I be able to avoid the deadlock that occurs?

Comment: probably. the difficult part is not to avoid deadlocks, it's to allow threads to run in parallel while avoiding deadlocks.otherwise you could just lock thread 1 on creation until thread 2 is finished

Answer (score 2):

Yes, lock(B) before lock(E) in T2 will prevent a deadlock. This is called a gate lock.